# How can I create a QuickTime reference movie (.mov)?

Tags: php, quicktime

I'd like to generate QuickTime Reference Movies from code (preferably PHP). The only way I've been able to do this so far is to "save for web" from QuickTime but that re-encodes everything. If I already have the files encoded (using ffmpeg or whatever) I'd prefer to avoid having to do that again just to create what is more or less a playlist.

Are there any .mov libraries for PHP?

Answer (score 1):

try http://www.phpclasses.org/package/1946-PHP-Generate-Quicktime-Reference-Movie-files.html